# SSCollectionView SSCollectionViewItem - no Items displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview, sstoolkit

I ran into difficulties with SSCollectionView and SSCollectionViewItem.

First of all I'd like to get it initialized from IB. But that won't work for me.
I have a SelectFooViewController which is:

```
@interface SelectFooViewController : SSCollectionViewController { ... }
```

and am using it as filesOwner of the corresponding XIB.

```
 SelectFooViewController* selectFooVC = [[SelectFooViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"SelectFooViewController" bundle:nil];
```

But since it wont work I had to initialize its properties inside viewDidLoad() myself.

Furthermore I am not able to display anything except the backgroundColor of my SSCollectionViewItems. What I want is a textLabel and an image .

```
- (SSCollectionViewItem *)collectionView:(SSCollectionView *)aCollectionView itemForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SSCollectionViewItem *item = [[[SSCollectionViewItem alloc] initWithStyle:SSCollectionViewItemStyleImage reuseIdentifier:itemIdentifier] autorelease];

    SSLabel* label = [[SSLabel alloc] init];
    [label setText:@"foo"];
    item.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"]];
    item.textLabel = label;
    [label autorelease];

    return item;
}
```

I can confirm that the delegate methods (for determining the number Of rows, sections and such) are implemented and working as expected. But my items are all empty - but react onclick with the expected popup.

Does anyone see an error in what I did? - Thanks...

**EDIT: I was also not able to display a local image by changing SSCatalog project**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out, that I have to set the frame of each property (textLabel, detailTextLabel and imageView) myself. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create instance SelectFooViewController just insert this line

```
selectFooVC.view;
```

or

```
selectFooVC.view.hidden = NO;
```

And then add it to the view.

This is because the view is not initalised until you explicitly access it. Hence your items are loaded only when you click it and not immediately. You can call it a hack but i don't call it one. :-)

Comment: Thats the lazy loading I read about earlier. But strangely I never ran into trouble with that one. Sadly adding lines after my initWithNibName: call didn't change a thing...

Comment: Where are you adding the item returned from second part of your code?

Comment: Have you set the delegates and calling reload appropriately?

Comment: That is a delegate Method of SSCollectionViewDataSource. Its called when from the SSToolkit framework when SCCollectionView requests items for displaying.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the delegates are set correctly. I debug-stepped over  _collectionView.dataSource = self;
  _collectionView.delegate = self; where self is the ViewController. The problem I have is, that my Items are only displaying the backgroundColor property - but nothing else, like a custom image or a label.

Comment: And is the collectionview outlet connected?